# How can I make C++ count user input after it hit the enter key?

Tags: c++, for-loop, user-input

So I am making a tic tac toe game, user vs pc with a simple random generator. What I was planning was to make a counter of how many times the user inputs a choice on the tic tac toe board. That way I can generate a random number, and place it in a vector, as many as the user inputs so that it can play. Each option is labeled with a number on the tic tac toe board, and the corresponding number will change to the mark depending on the which player is X and O, using an array.

Here is what I have currently:

```
srand(time(0));
int AIrandom,playerSelection,random, counter = 0;
int i;
int player = i,choice;
char mark;

vector<int> AI;
cout << "Would like to be player one or two? >";
cin >> playerSelection;
// Mark will equal to X if player wants to be 1, if false then mark is O 
mark = (playerSelection == 1) ? 'X' : 'O';

cout << "Player " << mark << ", enter a number >";
cin >> choice;
//Count the amount of times user input so we know how many times to show AI's choice
for(; choice != '\n'; counter++)
{
    cin >> choice;
}
cout << "User inputted " << counter << " times" << endl;
//If player decides to be player 1, The AI will be player 2 & has 4 tries 
if(playerSelection == 1 || playerSelection == 2)
{
    for(int i =0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        random = rand() % 9 + 1;
        AI.push_back(random);
    }
}

//Takes out value of the corresponding element, while it is less than the counter
for(int k; k < counter; k++)
{
    //From the corresponding element, that value will be their choice
    cout << "AI choice: " << AI[k] << endl;
    random = choice;
}
```

As you can see I made a for loop so that when choice does not equal a new line, it should count the amount of inputs–this is all in a do while loop, so it will continue doing it, this is just a portion of the code. After it generated a random number, depending on how many times the user has inputted, a for loop will take out a value of the vector.

I know because choice is an integer, it wont register "\n" because it is a string input but essentially that is what I want to do. How would I be able to count the amount of inputs after the user has hit enter when they finalized their choice in this game?

P.S I am worried about repeating values from the random generator but I was thinking of using a sorting method and removing any repeats and trying again but I am not sure if that is a very efficient method. If you have any thoughts or ideas you can suggest I'd appreciate very much!

Comment: IMHO, you can't count the player's moves without alternating with the Computer/AI.  The Tic-Tac-Toe game is based on alternating moves.  The next move is usually based on the previous moves of all players.  You don't know ahead of time, the quantity of moves from either player.  So, I don't understand the logic of your program.

Comment: In your logic, how do you handle the case where player and AI have the same move, since you asked for player moves without the alternation?

Comment: Another {board} game you may be interested in is "Swashbuckler" (or something similar).  Each player would write down their next N moves on paper.  After all the moves were written down, then each "round" evaluation would begin.  For example, round 1 would be player 1's first move, player 2's first move, etc.  The game was interesting because you would plan on picking up a chair and hit a player, but the player wasn't where you predicted him to be.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes we the computer does not know what to choose, however this program is meant to be on "easy mode" where it has no strategy to win. I am supposed to make 3 versions of this game, human vs human, human vs dumb AI, and human vs smart AI. With the smart AI I was thinking of creating lines of pre-made choices in order to make the AI "challenging against the player".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews wish I had posted this earlier then :( but this is a project that is due by the end of the week, and I already worked so much on this haha. But it does sound interesting and would work on that during my winter break so I can continue practicing

Comment: A note:  When choice takes a value of 10, it will match choice =='\n'  as '\n' ascii value is 10.
As for treating "\n" as  end of input, You will have to read choice as  as string (char-array) and compare if choice[0] == '\0'  to check if user has just pressed entered.